# Why do I get segmentation fault using fopen?

Tags: c, client-server, fopen, fifo

I'm writing a client-server model in C which works using fifos. I send a file name plus a name for a unique fifo for the client to recieve the data from the client and the server opens the file and writes the first line of it on the fifo. The thing is that even if the file exists i get a segmentation fault when opening it. Seems like the `fopen()` function works but I still get the error. If the file doesn't exist it just sends an empty string.

Here is `client.c` :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSIZE 512

struct sent {
   char name[BUFSIZE];
   char fifo[BUFSIZE];
};


int main()
{
   char name[BUFSIZE];
   char recieved[BUFSIZE];

   int client_server_fifo;
   char cs_fifo[BUFSIZE] = "cs_fifo";

   int server_client_fifo;
   char sc_fifo[BUFSIZE];
   sprintf(sc_fifo, "sc_fifo_%d", getpid());

   struct sent *sent;

   mkfifo(sc_fifo, 0777); 

   while(1) {
      printf("Write the name of the file: ");
      scanf("%s", name);

      printf("1111\n");
      client_server_fifo = open(cs_fifo, O_WRONLY);
      printf("2222\n");
      
      printf("%s", name);
      printf("%s", cs_fifo);

      sent->name = name;
      sent->fifo = cs_fifo;

      printf("%s", name);
      printf("%s", cs_fifo);

      write(client_server_fifo, sent, sizeof(*sent));

      server_client_fifo = open(sc_fifo, O_RDONLY);

      if (read(server_client_fifo, recieved, sizeof(recieved)) == -1) {
         printf("An error ocurred.\n");
      } else {
         printf("First line of the file: \n%s\n", recieved);
         close(client_server_fifo);
         close(server_client_fifo);
      }
      memset(recieved, 0, sizeof(recieved));
   }

   return 0;
}
```

And here's `server.c` :

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSIZE 512

struct sent {
   char name[BUFSIZE];
   char fifo[BUFSIZE];
};


int main()
{
   int client_server_fifo;
   char cs_fifo[BUFSIZE] = "cs_fifo";

   int server_client_fifo;
   char sc_fifo[BUFSIZE];

   struct sent *sent;

   char name[BUFSIZE]; 
   char line[BUFSIZE]; 

   FILE *file; 

   printf("Server running...\n");
     
   mkfifo(cs_fifo, 0777); 
   
   while (1)
   {
      client_server_fifo = open(cs_fifo, O_RDONLY); 

      read(client_server_fifo, sent, sizeof(*sent)); 

      strcpy(name, sent->name);
      strcpy(sc_fifo, sent->fifo);

      if((file = fopen(name, "r")) != NULL) { 
         printf("%s\n", name);
         fgets(line, BUFSIZE, file); 
         printf("%s\n", name);
      }
    
      server_client_fifo = open(sc_fifo, O_WRONLY);

      write(server_client_fifo, line, strlen(line)); 
      
      memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
      memset(line, 0, sizeof(line));

      close(client_server_fifo);

   }
   return 0;
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] of the program that crashes. And then run it in a debugger to locate exactly when and where the crash happens, and examine the values of involved variables.

Comment: I'm doing this in a remote server using ssh. Here I have 3 files called fitx1, fitx2 and fitx3. When sending a file name from the client the server works fine until the if where the fopen is, it doesn't print what's inside of it and then the execution stops with the segmentation fault.

Comment: A few points though: Why do you use `malloc` for the single `sent` structure? What happens if you fail to open the file (especially, what is the contents of `line` in that case)? Are all strings null-terminated? And what happens if there are errors anywhere else (always do error checking!)?

Comment: And if you haven't done it yet, then *please* Take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Who is teaching you to cram code into one line like this: `if (read(server_client_fifo, recieved, sizeof(recieved)) == -1)`?  Good luck trying to fully handle everything `read()` can return when you cram the call into an `if` statement like that.  `read()` can return ***any*** value up to and including the amount of bytes you requested be read.  It can return `-1` on failure.  It can return `0` on EOF.  It can return a partial result, meaning you have to call `read()` again.  You can't handle all that when the call is stuffed into an `if()` statement.  Also, `read()` doesn't produce a string.

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behavior because in gthis statement

```
sprintf(sc_fifo, "sc_fifo_%d", getpid());
```

you are trying to change a string literal pointed to by the pointer `sc_fifo`.

```
char *cs_fifo = "cs_fifo";
```

When you declare a pointer to a string literal always declare them with the qualifier `const`. In this case you will get ban error at compilation time if you will tray to change a string literal.

Also you are using uninitialized pointer sent

```
struct sent *sent;
```

in this statement

```
read(client_server_fifo, sent, sizeof(*sent));
```

There are other errors. For example arrays do not have the assignment operator. So these statements in `client.c`

```
  sent->name = name;
  sent->fifo = cs_fifo;
```

are incorrect.